# Updating nested arrays with mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested

So I'm basically developing a time-series schema for my code;

```
var GameStatisticsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
game: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', required: true }, 
months: [
  { // monthly viewers
      epoch: { type: Number, required: true }, // entry time stamp
      weeks: [
        { // weekly viewers
            epoch: { type: Number, required: true }, // entry time stamp
            days: [
              { // daily viewers
                  epoch: { type: Number, required: true }, // entry time stamp
                  hours: [
                    { // hourly viewers
                      epoch: { type: Number, required: true }, // entry time stamp
                      statistics: [
                        { // per minute statistics.
                            viewers: { type: Number },
                            channels: { type: Number },
                        }]
                  }]
            }]
      }]
}]
});
```

Basically the data is stored as - so i can query per day, per minute, per week data as i like to;

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56a78e337a9a34f8a368f719"), 
"game" : ObjectId("56a6f0b5bbfbbad0550450ee"), 
"months" : {
    "1" : {
        "weeks" : {
            "5" : {
                "days" : {
                    "26" : {
                        "hours" : {
                            "17" : {
                                "statistics" : {
                                    "18" : {
                                        "channels" : NumberInt(46), 
                                        "viewers" : NumberInt(308)
                                    }
                                }, 
                                "epoch" : NumberInt(1453820400)
                            }
                        }, 
                        "epoch" : NumberInt(1453759200)
                    }
                }, 
                "epoch" : NumberInt(1453672800)
            }
        }, 
        "epoch" : NumberInt(1451599200)
    }
}, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Basically I'm using findOneAndUpdate() to insert my per-minute sensor data;

```
function updateStatistics(game, data) {

 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    // get current time
    var now = moment();

    var minute = now.minute();
    var hour = now.hour();
    var day = now.date();
    var week = now.week();
    var month = now.month() + 1; // moment months are 0 indexed

    // we'll store per hour, day, week and month subdocuments. so set the epochs for those.
    var update = {};
    update["months." + month + ".epoch"] = moment().startOf('month').unix();
    update["months." + month + ".weeks." + week + ".epoch"] = moment().startOf('isoWeek').unix();
    update["months." + month + ".weeks." + week + ".days." + day + ".epoch"] = moment().startOf('day').unix();
    update["months." + month + ".weeks." + week + ".days." + day + ".hours." + hour + ".epoch"] = moment().startOf('hour').unix();

    // set the viewers & channels.
    update["months." + month + ".weeks." + week + ".days." + day + ".hours." + hour + ".statistics." + minute + ".viewers"] =  data.viewers;
    update["months." + month + ".weeks." + week + ".days." + day + ".hours." + hour + ".statistics." + minute + ".channels"] =  data.channels;

    GameStatistics.findOneAndUpdate(
      { "game": game._id },
      { $set: update },
      {
          new: true, // return the updated document
          upsert: true, // create the document if does not exist
          runValidators: true,
          setDefaultsOnInsert: true
      },
      function(err, document) {

          if(err)
            reject(err);

          resolve();
      }
    );
  });
  }
```

The thing is that once i enable;

```
runValidators: true,
setDefaultsOnInsert: true
```

My validator will fire the exception;

```
 Cannot update 'months.1.epoch' and 'months' at the same time
```

So if I disable runValidators, i can store the data as so, but the document becomes schema-less - and turns identicial to this;

```
var GameStatisticsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
game: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', required: true }, 
months: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Mixed }]
```

});

So any workarounds you can suggest?

The reason I'm using upset enabled findOneAndUpdate is that, without that I don't know how to create nested array values and save() the document.

Bear in mind that - for 26.01.2015 15:35:13, the code need to insert into this;

```
months[1].weeks[5].days[26].hours[15].minutes[35].statistics.{
 viewers = 25;
 channels = 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a timestamp alone?

```
var GameStatisticsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    game: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', required: true  }, 
    timestamp: { type: DateTime },
    viewers: { type: Number },
    channels: { type: Number }
});
```

This makes updating simple and you can use dateTime queries for month/day/etc.

For the last month the query would be:

```
{ game: gameId, timestamp: { $gt: <date from a month ago>}}
```

But you'll need to use the mongoose aggregate function which I'm not too familiar with.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate-js

Comment: Because i'd like to get per-week, per-day, per-hour, per-month data. With your suggestion, given that timestamp data frequency is per-minute, you'll be only able to query per-minute data. With my current schema, i can query for example the per-week data by averaging the values for the date-range i need.

Comment: You can do the same with a date query, averaging all results: find({ date: { $gt: new Date(2016, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2016, 1, 1) }}) for all stats in January

Comment: Okay please show me how to get data for last 4 weeks with it? By averaging i mean that, i can hook the schema update and calculate the per-period averages on the document and then it'll be a simple access operation.